# How to regex search this pattern

Tags: regex, svg, replace

I have a set of styles, like this:

```
.CONSTANT {fill:#22FFCC}
.CONSTANT {fill:#0000FF}
.CONSTANT2 {fill:black}
.CONSTANT3 {fill:#98FF00}
```

and I would need a regex that can recognize the pattern so that I can use it in `str.replace('pattern', 'replacement')`. The idea is, I know what the constants are, they are indicators of the class, but I have no idea what the color of the class actually is, so what is the best way to "capture" the entire line as given above, or rather capture a certain name `CONSTANT` + `whitespace( )` + `{` + `whateverComesNextUntilTheClosingBrackets` + `}` in order to replace it with something else.

Idea is to be able to make a shifting of colors within an SVG image, regardless of what the color used to be, the SVG image however is not an actual image it is a string which I can run through to replace the needed parts.

Comment: I´m not sure I understood your question correctly. Are you searching for something like this: #[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z] ?
Besides of that, I always use this page to test my regexes: http://rubular.com/

Comment: I will check it out, one sec!

Comment: CSS is not easy to use with regex because of white space. You should consider other ways to do this: [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule), creating `<style>` tags dynamically, or including/changing CSS dynamically (adding new `<link>` element). [`str.replace(/\{fill\:(?:\s+)?[^\}]+\}/, '{fill:new-color}')`](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5C%7Bfill%5C%3A(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B)%3F(%5B%5E%5C%7D%5D%2B)%5C%7D)

Comment: I was maybe not clear enough, I would try to re-explain it, but Frederico got the solution down there and it works just the way I want it. The goal was to be able to change the `"CONSTANT"` part, and have the regex return the entire `CONSTANT` + `whatever comes next in the brackets`

Comment: There is almost certainly a better approach to whatever you are trying to do than parsing and rewriting CSS yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your statement:

> whitespace( ) + { + whateverComesNextUntilTheClosingBrackets + }

You can use a regex like this:

```
\.CONSTANT \{.*?\}
```

**[Working dmeo](https://regex101.com/r/eKqZdo/1)**

Comment: @Dellirium, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

.CONSTANT\d*\s*{fill:(#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]{4,})}

With the examples you have provided, this should do the trick.

```
\.  ->  for starting with a dot(needed to add \ to take . as text not as regex)
CONSTANT  ->  to match string exactly as it is
\d*   ->  may or may not have digits
\s*   ->  may or may not have spaces here
{fill:  ->  match exactly as it is
```

now a new group is created using brackets () to limit the effect of 'OR' condition using '|'. without these brackets, it will take whole string before '|' as one vs string after ie. (.CONSTANT\d*\s*{fill:(#[0-9A-F]{6}) OR ([a-z]{4,})}). But we need (#[0-9A-F]{6}) OR ([a-z]{4,})

```
#   -> match exactly.
[0-9A-F]{6} -> to match hex values for color containing digits and letter from A-F with length exactly 6.

[a-z]{4,}   -> to match color names with length **at least** of 4 like blue
```

This will cover both #hex_code_color or color name  and black)

Comment: Thanks for elaborate explenation, and welcome to stackoverflow. It seems hella complex though and quite specific, works, that is great, though Frederico's solution is more "straight to a point" whilst yours would really target only properly written CSS and color codes and whatnot. Both suit me fine, his is just simpler. Thanks for explaining how yours works!

Answer (score 0):

To replace only the color you can use backreferences, so that you don't have to replace the whole string. 
This regex `(^\.[^ ]+ *{ *fill: *)([^}]+)` allows to replace the string with `'$1yournewcolor'`.
[Here is a working demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cr0G4x/1)

Comment: Would be very useful if I didn't know the name or needed to replace all the constants, but I specifically need to replace them one by one to get different colors. Frederico's solution gave me exactly what I needed, though yours could be used as well with some minor modifications. Thanks!